# Ideal sheaf at a smooth point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose X is a smooth projective variety and $z\in X$ is a smooth point, $m_z$ is corresponding ideal sheaf on X. Then why $m_z$ is locally free ?

Comment: That is only true for curves.

Comment: @seshadri: If things are clear, could you accept and thereby close the question?

Answer (score 5):

I'll elaborate a bit on MooS' comment.

Passing to the stalk at $z$, the problem is the following: Given a regular local Noetherian ring $R$ (it's not necessary to assume that it's the local ring at a smooth point) with maximal ideal ${\mathfrak m}$ and residue field $k=R/{\mathfrak m}$, when is ${\mathfrak m}$ free? Looking at the short exact sequence $0\to {\mathfrak m}\to R\to k\to 0$ of $R$-modules, we see that ${\mathfrak m}$ is free if and only if $k$ has projective dimension at least $1$. However, for a regular local ring one always has $\text{pdim}_R(k)=\text{kr.dim}(R)$, so indeed ${\mathfrak m}$ is free if and only if $R$ has dimension $0$ or $1$. Transferring back to your question, this gives MooS' assertion that the claim holds if and onlf if $X$ is discrete or a curve.

*Please see MooS' comment below for a simpler non-homological argument.*

Comment: I think the argument from homological algebra is a little bit overkill, isn't it? In general an ideal is free if and only if it is principal with a regular generator. Principal maximal ideals occur only in dimension at most $1$ as Krull's principal ideal theorem states.

Comment: @MooS: You're absolutely right, that's much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @Hanno Thank you very much.

Comment: @seshadri Can this be closed?